# View Não Atualizável em SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Galera como fazer uma  View  não atualizável em SQL Server, pois não estou encontrando documentação que contenha um script desses.

Comment: View não atualizável?

Comment: Como assim jovem? Qual a necessidade então?

Comment: E para o trabalho de faculdade, também não entendi a necessidade!

Answer (score 1):

Na documentação de [CREATE VIEW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql) consta algo sobre *updatable views* e quais são as regras para obtê-las. Ao se *quebrar* alguma das regras, me parece que temos uma exibição não atualizável.

Por exemplo:

```
   -- código #1   
   CREATE VIEW nome_da_exibição as  
   SELECT colunas 
     from nome_tabela
   union all  
   SELECT colunas 
     from nome_tabela  
     where 1 = 0;  
   go
```

Também é possível utilizar procedimento *trigger* (do tipo INSTEAD OF) para bloquear execução de INSERT, UPDATE e DELETE na chamada da exibição.

Para aprofundar no tema, pesquise na web por [sql server view readonly](https://www.google.com.br/search?client=ubuntu&q=sql%20server%20view%20readonly).

Comment: obrigado gente... creio que deva ser dessa forma que o Jose repassou, obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais performática que conheço é:

```
CREATE VIEW MinhaView
AS
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Coluna1, Coluna2, Coluna3
FROM tabela
WITH CHECK OPTION
```